# Pandas extract columns and rows by ID from a distance matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matrix

I have a distance matrix with IDs as column and row names:

```
    A   B  C  D   
A   0   1  2  3
B   1   0  4  5
C   2   4  0  6
D   3   5  6  0
```

How to efficiently extract values from a large matrix, e.g. for IDs A and C to get this matrix:

```
    A   C    
A   0   2  
C   2   0
```

Edit, missing IDs in the matrix should be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for get values by labels:

```
vals = ['A','C']

df = df.loc[vals, vals]
print (df)
   A  C
A  0  2
C  2  0
```

EDIT: If some values not match and need omit them add [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
vals = ['J','A','C']

new = df.columns.intersection(vals, sort=False)
df = df.loc[new, new]
print (df)
   A  C
A  0  2
C  2  0
```

Comment: Thanks, I have some ids in  my list which are not in the matrix. How to ignore them? Otherwise I get a key error.